# how to get client_secret google api without google console?

Tags: google-api, credentials, google-developers-console

i have a question about getting client secret.
in google API doc, we need to enable and download JSON file from google console API. secret->credentials->API.

so in development that totally works fine. so i have a problem when in production. my app need get the API, but how to get client secret from code?
so while the user login/sign up. the user should not go and enable API first at the console.

its that possible to download client secret from code?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API for Google Developer console.  The only way to create a new client, enable APIs for it and get the Client secret. is to do so on the Google Developer console.

It is not possible to programmaticlly download the client secret.